# How to rebind Ctrl-[ in .vimrc

Tags: vim

In vim, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> acts like <kbd>Esc</kbd> by default. However, I would like to rebind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to perform a custom action. (Specifically, to <kbd>Ctrl-t</kbd> because I find it more natural for <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> to have complementary actions for ctags.)

However, when I execute the command:

`:nnoremap <C-[> <C-t>`

then my arrow key navigation get messed up. I'm not sure what happens, but clearly that's not the ideal way to do it.

I've tried to unbind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> but vim reports that it wasn't bound, and I've tried some tricks like first binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to itself and then unbinding. Always the same result.

Side note: Interestingly, when I add it to my `.vimrc` (as the last command) it's even worse. Something nondeterministic happens and vim opens randomly in one of these 3 states:

- The bottom status line says "E73: tag stack empty", implying it received a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>-esque command, however the if I hit a nav key like <kbd>j</kbd>, it deletes the current and bottom line and then puts me into insert mode. (Happens ~70% of the time.)
- Sometimes it's in replace mode. (Happens ~15% of the time.)
- Sometimes it's in normal mode. (Happens ~15% of the time.)

How can I properly remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to a different function in `.vimrc`?

Comment: `<C-[>` doesn't "act as `<Esc>`", it *is* `<Esc>` and the arrow keys are encoded as `<Esc>A`... Whatever you map to `<Esc>` will be executed whenever Vim expects an `<Esc>`.

Comment: `<C-t>` is mapped to `:pop` on my machine by default. Perhaps it's setup to be the same thing in your machine too.

Comment: @roomainl: Can you expound on "is `<Esc>`"?

Comment: @B-Con the escape key is literally encoded over a tty as `C-[`.  there is absolutely no distinction between pressing `Esc` and pressing `C-[`.  vim can't tell the difference, because there is no difference.  and since basically all ANSI keycodes begin with `Esc`/`C-[`, remapping it is making vim do crazy things in response to _all_ terminal input.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. It looks like rebinding `C-[` is impossible, then. If you write that up, that's a valid answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't rebind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>.  Pressing the Escape key in a terminal sends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>, just like pressing the Tab key sends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>.  There's no separate <kbd>Esc</kbd> code.

Vim is probably acting crazily when you try this because basically every ANSI key sequence starts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>, so your rebinding is firing on *all terminal input*, and whatever else is in the key sequence looks like more commands to vim.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.